# How to reuse correctly the cells in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I have a big problem with my UITableViewCell. I use storyboard and I have a custom cell into my UITableVIew. I add a Identifier to this, and my class code is:

```
static NSString *celldentifier = @"myCellId";

CustomCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:celldentifier];

    if (celldentifier == nil) {
        celldentifier = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:celldentifier];
    }
...
```

Edit:

```
...
myCell.myButton.hidden = YES;
...
```

When I load other information in cell and I need hide the button, I do a reload table:

```
[self.myTable reloadData];
```

And in my viewController I reload this tableView showing or hidding some components in my cell like a UIButton. But when I do scroll, this buttons added disappear..

What is wrong in my code? How could I solve this problem?

Comment: show the complete code. You need to track when you want to hide/show the components in cell.

Comment: The actual reason of the issue is below the three dots. But you should use this syntax `CustomCell *myCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:celldentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];` and delete the `celldentifier` check which will never be `nil`.

Comment: And the code you have doesn't really make sense.  `celldentifier = [[CustomCell alloc]`?

Comment: I have added the rest of code, is only the assign values to UIButton or hide/show this, and reload table from my reload function whith the new information in NSArray...

Comment: Your approach is completely wrong. You have to keep the `hidden` state for each cell in the model, to hide/show a button change the value in the model and reload the cell or the entire view. Further if you are going to change the state of an UI element in `cellForRow` in an `if` clause you have to add an `else` clause to set a default value.

Comment: Thank you @vadian this was my stupid error... I was forgotten show the button then reload and always was hidde.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that **cells are getting reused**.. if you have an **if statement to make a change**.. make sure to have **put the else so you revert it**

```
if(isReady){
    myCell.myButton.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    myCell.myButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myCell.myButton.hidden = YES;`

Its bad idea to use it out of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

You should create model for cell and keep there all properties for cell.

```
if (myCell == nil) {
    myCell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:celldentifier];
    //I think it should be but don't shure
    //[tableView registerClass:<#(nullable Class)#> forCellReuseIdentifier:<#(nonnull NSString *)#>];
}
```

Comment: What are those comments in the your code? How does the code in this answer help solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *celldentifier = @"myCellId";
CustomCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:celldentifier];
if (!myCell) {
    myCell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:celldentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and you should add `myCell.myButton.hidden = NO;` this code before `myCell.myButton.hidden = YES;`

Like this:

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCellId";

CustomCell * myCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (myCell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    myCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

myCell.myButton.hidden = NO;

if(isReady){
    myCell.myButton.hidden = YES;
}
```